# script for folder creation is not working anymore

Tags: php, function, post, mkdir

This code was working some days ago... now I'm not sure what is going wrong.. Could someone shed a light or propose a better idea ?

```
<?php
$album = $_POST['name'];
function create_album($album){
    $albumPath = "albums/".$album;
    if (is_dir($albumPath)){
        echo('Album already exists.');
    }
    else{
        mkdir($albumPath);
        echo ("The album $album was created successfully");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: My first guess would be: permissions. Can you verify that `mkdir` isn't throwing warnings, notices or errors? Enable error reporting and look in your error log.

Comment: Seems like you're not calling your `create_album()` function, not in posted code anyway. And since `$albumPath` is inside that function, then it's a scope issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a call to the function.

```
<?php
$album = $_POST['name'];
function create_album($album){
    $albumPath = "albums/".$album;
    if (is_dir($albumPath)){
        echo('Album already exists.');
    }
    else{
        mkdir($albumPath);
        echo ("The album $album was created successfully");
    }
}

create_album($album);
?>
```

Comment: @GiulioCorkoneFullnior **Are you serious right now?!** I saw this answer and I was like: *No f'in way. He just didn't paste the whole code.* OMG! #facepalm #facepunch

Comment: Goes to show how the OP didn't (bother) to read the first and [`initial comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047893/script-for-folder-creation-is-not-working-anymore#comment33428986_22047893) @CodeAngry - Classic #facepalm

Comment: Actually it's not that I didn't paste... I didn't write the function call... must have missed it while I was making the function since it was all dirty haha !